# how to stream records with pg-query-stream with async/await?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Using pg-query-stream/node-postgres, I'm attempting to implement a utility method which can be used to sequentially (and asynchronously) process each record from a query.

While processing each record the handler can return `false` to break out of the iteration and return immediately.

This utility method itself resolves to `true` if it iterated through all the records and the handler resolved `true` for every one, and it resolves `false` if the handler ever resolved `false`.

Below is what I've implemented, and it (mostly) appears to work perfectly.

However when under a lot of load, eventually my postgres pool gets into a completely non-responsive state - I'm guessing bad connections are getting returned to the pool, and the next command issued on them just hangs indefinitely? or something...of course I can't reproduce it reliably.

The docs on pg-query-stream are fairly sparse, so I'm not entirely confident I'm using it correctly:

- When I'm ending the stream early, is it correct to just call `stream.destroy()` and return the client to the pool?
- Should I even be calling `stream.destroy()` on successful completion and/or on error?
- Is it expected that the 'end' event does not honor the stream's 'paused' status?
- Is 'end' even the correct event to be using for this purpose or is 'close' more correct?
- What's the difference between 'end' and 'close'?

Any insights on proper usage are greatly appreciated, thanks!

```js
  public async forEachRecord(
    queryText: string,
    values: any[],
    recordHandler: (record: TRecord) => boolean | Promise<boolean>,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
  
    const query = new QueryStream(queryText, values);
    const client = await this.pool.connect();
    let error: any;
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      let hasEnded = false;

      query.on('data', async (data) => {
        query.pause();
        try {
          if (await recordHandler(data)) {
            query.resume();
            return;
          }
          resolve(false);
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        } finally {
          if (hasEnded) {
            resolve(true);
          }
        }
      });

      query.on('end', async () => {
        hasEnded = true;
        // 'end' can come while the last recordHandler() is still executing asynchronously, while the stream
        // is paused...so we need to do this check so the last recordHandler()'s return value is honored
        if (!query.isPaused()) {
          resolve(true);
        }
      });

      query.on('error', (err) => {
        error = err;
        reject(err);
      });

      client.query(query);

    }).finally(() => {
      query.destroy();
      client.release(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `pool.query`? It would handle the cleanup itself.

Comment: Since node streams implement the async iterator interface, I'd recommend to use `for await (const data of query) { if (!await recordHandler(data)) return false; } return true;`

Comment: Thanks Bergi , I have switched my implementation to this approach and it does appear to work perfectly without issues when under load. I am still very curious what was wrong with my original implementation , but If you want to submit this as an answer I will accept it 

Comment: That I don't know either, but it's good to know that the simple code does everything right by default :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I've just implemented [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator) for this purpose:

```
import {Pool} from 'pg';
import {QueryIterablePool} from 'pg-iterator';

const pool = new Pool(/* connection config */);

const q = new QueryIterablePool(pool); // creating our Pool container

const i = q.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [123]);

for await(const u of i) {
    console.log(u); // output each row
}
```

See more [complete examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator/wiki/Examples) within the library.

Comment: Why the wrapper? Doesn't `pg-query-stream` already do just this, like the example in my comment?

Comment: @Bergi See [the top note there](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator) about the many extra things it does.

Comment: @vitaly-t what if you wanted to run an update statement inside that for loop? lets say you load all rows from a table and for each row you compute something and save it back to another table

Comment: You can do `pool.query('UPDATE...')` inside that loop.